# Errors Installing Xfce GUI

Tags: xfce, gui

When trying to install Xfce, I'm encountering errors, related to the fact that packages within the extracted install files are not being found on the server, as follows:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/cpp-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb Connection failed 
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-urw-base35/fonts-urw-base35_20170801.1-3_all.deb Connection failed 
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit2gtk/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.28.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb Connection failed 
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/ubuntu-touch-sounds/ubuntu-touch-sounds_15.08_all.deb Connection failed
```

In turn, this is not allowing me to launch Xfce GUI. I feel like I have tried everything (for the last 7 or so hours).

I previously had Kali Linux installed, but have uninstalled it and I'm trying to run the setup through Ubuntu.

Comment: startxfce4

Command 'startxfce4' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install xfce4-session

I run apt-installxfc4-session and then same thing, failing to fetch data.. Have tried reinstalling Ubuntu, dist-upgrade etc etc.. Nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The only thing I haven't tried is editing the source list, don't really want to play with that just yet. Have had a look at the bash file and made the changes as per instructions.Im relatively new to this so let me know if Im not really making sense or you need some more info to clarify. Thanks

Comment: The best way to use Xfce is to install Xubuntu.  There is no "xfce app"; a desktop environment is comprised of dozens and dozens of packages. It's generally not a good idea to switch the DE.  This is the reason that Ubuntu maintains distinct flavors.

Comment: You have to fix your network connectivity and then install Xubuntu meta package by `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop^` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Start in text-only mode

```
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with Advanced options.

Select the line ending with (recovery mode)

Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
```

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt.

```
Press Return with this option highlighted.
```

The PC will start in a terminal.

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /

mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of gnome that are not necessary in Ubuntu Xfce

```
 aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Install xubuntu-desktop

```
 apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
 deborphan

 apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)

 deborphan --libdevel

 apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)

 deborphan --find-config

 dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
 apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
 apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```